# Get all odd days between date range in python

Tags: python

I tried in python still I didn't get odd and even Wednesday from the given date range. Example. If I give date range 02-11-2018 to 30-11-2018, I need to find all odd Thursdays and even Thursdays in python

Comment: show us what have you tried till yet

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import date, timedelta, datetime

curr = "1-12-2018"
end = "30-12-2018"
format = "%d-%m-%Y"
start_date = datetime.strptime(curr, format)
end_date = datetime.strptime(end, format)

step = timedelta(1)
num_wed = 0
off_days = ['Wed']

days = (end_date - start_date).days
for x in range(days):
    day = start_date.strftime("%a")
    if day in off_days:
        num_wed += 1
        if((num_wed%2!=0)):
                date = start_date.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
                print(date)
    start_date += step

print(num_wed)
```

It's working fine now